# How to deal with multiple jar handling issue?

Tags: android, jar, compiler-errors, runtime, apk

I have been noticing one major problem in android that

When I use/import couple of jars in my android app for development purpose so I get below exception:

```
[2011-10-23 16:23:29 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/myapp/R$array;
[2011-10-23 16:23:29 - myProj] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/myapp/R$array;
```

I have been noticing this problem when I import/use different jars for app development. I got to

> Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Order & Export->
>    Then assign jars priorities.

And then I go for running project so I get this exception. And every time I struggle to solve this issue. I know this issue raise due to common contents of jar but ant to know reliable way to handle it.

That's why I want to know how to deal with this?

Comment: First of please check console logs, and also set same version of support library in all libraries and app

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue multiple dex files means your application have different source for same class.

To fix it i used use same jar file(android-support-v4.jar) for project and libraries also. (copied same jar file in project and library).

Comment: So do you mean this issue arises only because of this android-support-v4.jar?

Comment: I have  fixed my issue by same process. So may be it will help full for you.

Answer (score 0):

This issue arises not only with the android-support-v4.jar, it can arises with other libraries too. This generally comes when you import some library in your project.

To resolve this just figure out which jar is showing the multiple dex issue and make sure to have the same jar in your project and as well as in the libraries which you have imported. Doing this your problem will be resolved.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I agree with your first statement. Can you please explain your second paragraph in detail?

Comment: Sorry for being late. I am explaining this to you with an example. 
Suppose you have multiple dex issue with android-support-v4.jar. There is a library which you have assigned to your project also contains the same lib which is android-support-v4.jar. Inspite of having the same library in two projects, these libraries are different. You just need to copy one android-support-v4.jar and past the copied jar in all the projects which are associated to your current one. I hope you understand this time.

Answer (score 0):

Check out all jar files added in lib folder of your project and all dependent library and remove jar if it is already added in another project or lib. This error will be only because of more than one source for same class.